# Embed shiny app into a jupyter notebook

Tags: r, shiny, jupyter

Is there anyway to embed a shiny app into a jupyter notebook?
After uploadind the ui.R and server.R files to the same folder where the notebook is, I have tried this code:

```
%R library(shiny)
%R runApp()
```

The app executes correctly but it opens a new window. I want to embed the app in the notebook.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: maybe you can use an iframe?

Comment: this is not as trivial as you think.

Answer (score 2):

Shiny and Jupyter people are [thinking about it](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1484) (June 2016).